# Free online 3d data visualization tool

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

I searched for a long time an online tool to plot 3d data, without luck. I even tried to create my own:

http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/3d/space-explorer-tracker.html?orbiter=-168&body=@499

[image: 3d plot]

(use data below to show a meaningful 3d chart)

[image: input data]

But it is still a little buggy and I have to manually update the source every time data format changes, and I should write an entirely new page in case I want to plot different 3d data...

Does anybody know an online free service to plot data from an online live datasource like [this](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi?batch=1&MAKE_EPHEM=%27YES%27&TABLE_TYPE=%27VECTORS%27&OUT_UNITS=%27KM-S%27&REF_SYSTEM=%27J2000%27&VEC_LABELS=%27YES%27&CSV_FORMAT=%27YES%27&OBJ_DATA=%27no%27&VEC_TABLE=%273%27&STEP_SIZE=%2710m%27&START_TIME=%272020-10-1%2000:00%27&STOP_TIME=%272020-10-2%2000:00%27&COMMAND=%27-168%27&CENTER=%27@499%27&)?

I should just specify the start/end markers of actual data, and the column to be plotted.

It cannot be a standalone SW because I want to be able to share my charts with people without need for them to install any software.

Comment: no, I am already using plotly javascript library. I need a web site, not a library. And I want to be able to share my charts with people without asking to install SW. (I will add this to the question)

Comment: I cannot understand if/how I can script Geogebra to make it dynamically load an external CSV file and use it as datasource.

Comment: Plotly chart studio doesn't support anymore remote-linked CSV files as sources in free version.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb) would be my preferred pick for your use case.

Colaboratory tool with zero configuration required, free, dynamic linking to any online CSV sheet, easy sharing, plotting 3D graphs is fairly straightforward in Python even if you are not a programmer, free access to GPUs, huge community content/support.

You may refer to my separate answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3859596/834711) for a working example (collaborative piece of code for a plot with data source linked to dynamic CSV sheet)